# How to read the hex value from ibeacon

Tags: java, hex, ibeacon

I have a list of some JSON array that contains the information of the Ibeacon which are transmitted through the IoT gateway to my server. There is some unknown information coming up in this JSON with the name of rawData which is some hex value. I want to decode/parse this information to know further but have no clue how I can do this. Here is an example:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-12-09T22:30:48.318Z",
    "mac": "BC233FAC9622",
    "rssi": -58,
    "rawData": "0201060303F1FF1716FDA50693A4E24FB1AFCFC6EB0764782527114CB9C564"
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2022-12-09T22:30:48.415Z",
    "mac": "BC233FAC9622",
    "rssi": -53,
    "rawData": "0201061AFF4C000215FDA50693A4E24FB1AFCFC6EB0764782527114CB9C5"
  }
```

Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [this iBeacon packet structure](https://wiki.aprbrother.com/en/iBeacon_Packet.html#ibeacon-packet-structure). It seems first 9 bytes of second item of JSON use default values for iBeacon prefix :

```
0201061AFF4C000215 -> iBeacon Prefix
FDA50693A4E24FB1AFCFC6EB07647825 -> Proximity UUID
27114CB9C5
```